# How to do [(mean) +- (2*standard deviation)]

Tags: r, mean, standard-deviation, arithmetic-expressions

I'm new to R and I'm trying to understand how to do the mean +- 2 times standard deviation. I've tried calculating the mean and the standard deviation singularly and then do the aritmetic calculation but everything I try to do gives me error.

```r
mean <- aggregate(data$distance, list(data$dose), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE) 
sd <- aggregate(data$distance, list(data$dose), FUN=sd, na.rm=TRUE)
mean_sd <- ("mean", "%+-%", "2*(sd)")
```

where data is my initial data, distance is the value from which I want to do the mean and standard deviation and the different doses are the groups.

It gives me:

```r
mean_sd <- ("mean", "%+-%", "2*(sd)")
# Error: unexpected ',' in "mean_sd <- ("mean","
```

After this, I also wanted to select the IDs from the data that have the mean higher or smaller than the value I'll find (mean +- 2 sd).
For instance, I have several IDs, for each of them I have several doses and the value of the distance.

Comment: What is `mean_sd <- ("mean", "%+-%", "2*(sd)")` supposed to be doing? If you're hoping to make a string vector, you need the `c` before it, ala `mean_sd <- c("mean", "%+-%", "2*(sd)")`. If you're moping to _execute_ those strings as an expression, then that's different ... and I don't know where it would be suggested to try that way.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Federica Gilardini! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a great start here!); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Try `mean_sd <- mean + c(-1, 1)*2*sd`. Also, `mean` and `sd` already are R functions' names, use other names. For instance, `xbar` and `S`.

Comment: Or, with the names in my previous comment, `mean_sd <- c(lower = xbar -2*S, upper = xbar + 2*S)`. See `help("c")`.